# Definition of One-point compactification

Tags: general-topology, geometry, compactness, geometric-topology

My question is an elementary one but I can't seem to find the formal definition.
If $M$ and $N$ are topological spaces and $\dot{M}$ is the one-point compactification of $M$ then how is a map $f:M \rightarrow N$ precesely lifted to a map $\dot{f}:\dot{M} \rightarrow \dot{N}$?

Comment: It isn't, necessarily. For instance, if $M = N = \Bbb R$, and $f$ is the identity, then it won't work at all. Do you maybe mean lifted to a map $\dot f:\dot M \to \dot N$?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what i meant.

Comment: Not every map has an extension. The projection $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ onto the first factor cannot be extended to a map $S^2\to S^1$. The map $f$ must be proper, and that's sufficient for the existence of an extension to the one-point compactifications.

Comment: So are there any linear functionals $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that are proper (say if $E\not\cong \mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: No. Remember that the definition of proper is "$f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K$". Now take $K =\{0\}$.